# In Angular JS, How can I use "KeyEvent" without <input> element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was writing a calculator program.

I want the program to catch "keyEvent" when I just press the key to the view directly.

How can I use the KeyEvent without input element?

This is my code.(with  element).

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="keyCheck($event)"/>
```

To use the Key Event without  element, I tried to put the "ng-keydown " directive to body element.
like this:

```
<body ng-keydown="keyCheck($event)">
```

However, Nothing has happened.

What do I have to do to use the keyEvent directly in screen?

What I want is that :

When I just put the key "7" without click to anywhere, my calculator sense it. That's what I want.

Comment: I don't think Angular supports keydown events on the body? Regular DOM and javascript does however.

Comment: @DavinTryon Thank you Davin!! It's really helped! Good day!!